# Add JTree to JPanel in a ActionPerformed

Tags: java, swing

Here is the Complete Verifiable Minimal Example of my problem, I believe and hope.
If the JTree created with a DefaultMutableTreeNode added directly from the initialize () method adds me correctly (The line annotated code). But if I try from ActionPerformed method for you to operate a button, the JTree does not appear.

```
public class Window {
private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Window() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JMenu mnAbrir = new JMenu("Open");
    menuBar.add(mnAbrir);

    JMenuItem mntmAbrirXml = new JMenuItem("Open JTree");
    mntmAbrirXml.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode mutable = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            JTree tree = new JTree(mutable);
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(tree);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            //System.out.println("Is into ActionPerformed");

        }
    });
    mnAbrir.add(mntmAbrirXml);
    //JTree treeOut = new JTree(new DefaultMutableTreeNode());
    //frame.getContentPane().add(treeOut, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

}
```

Thanks again, Topo.

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: You _could_ `revalidate()` the enclosing container and `repaint()`, but `tree.setModel(abrirXmlTree())` seems preferable.

Comment: *"Added missing code"*  No, I expect @MadProgrammer meant an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Voting to close for lack of one or the other..

Comment: Here is the Complete Verifiable Minimal Example of my problem, I believe and hope.

Answer (score 0):

Do not really know why but must make visible inside the main frame ActionPerformed. This is the line of code is missing (WITHIN THE actionPerformed):

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```